# MathJax is being rendered even though "\$" is used

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax

When I open [this answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1500/3170) in the iOS app, I know what I supposed to see: a dollar sign, the number 20, a space, the word "to", another space, a dollar sign, and the number 50. Instead I see the number 20, the word "to" in italics, and the number 50, with no spaces or dollar signs.

It seems like the app is forcing the MathJax to render, even when there's slashes before the dollar signs. I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

[image: screenshot of undesirable behavior]

Comment: In case it's outdated, I'm using 1.2.2

Comment: The double negative in your title is stange: "MathJax refuses to not render" ~ "MathJax does render"...

Comment: Fwiw, the Android app honors the escaping in the linked question.

Comment: Looks like the way we do MathJax in the app is broken.  On electronics `\$ this is math \$` so we added it to the list and broke all other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The problem was that the web has a few permutations of MathJax:

- Most sites support `$inline math$` and `\\(inline math\\)` but EE uses `\$inline math\$`.
- Most sites use the extensions `'AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js','noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'` but Chem uses `'mhchem.js'`.

Because the web implemented customization as freeform text and the customization was not exposed over the API, we simply used all the options and hoped for the best.

Kevin looked at how we are using things and added two new extension strings, `EscapedMathJaxDelimiters` and `MHChemMathJax`, to the next version of the API representing the two variations mentioned above.  The apps will use these to configure MathJax.