# Is there an easy way of finding out what MathJax extensions are enabled on every main site?

Tags: support, mathjax

On sites that have MathJax enabled I'd like to get a list of the extensions in use (for example mhchem on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)).

I realise I can get it from the page source

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
                                    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
                                    TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js"], noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } },
                                    messageStyle: "none"
            });
```

(the `TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js"]`) part) but I was hoping for it to be included in the API or data dump etc so I don't have to screen scrape. Is there any alternative to screen scraping every SE site?

Comment: Hmm... the API doesn't say anything about this.  https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#page=6&filter=default

Comment: Yeah, i did have a look; you can find out if MathJax is enabled, but not what extensions.

Comment: There's also this answer which talks about exposing it in the API, although that might just be for their app: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251229/161467

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need this information for? It might be easier to help with a concrete use case.

Comment: As far as I can see it is manually documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/158100)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: I'm trying to get the MathML of equations within a post. Currently I'm running MathJax on the post's HTML wrapped to make it a valid page. This works but isn't 100% correct because of the variations in delimiters and extensions between the different sites.

Comment: @Rene: Thanks, that could be as good as it's going to get. I'll wait a bit just in case, but if you want to make that an answer then I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks, @George Since the question is just about extensions, have you tried the autoload-all extension? http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#autoload-all Since SE only uses standard MathJax extensions, that should be enough?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: Good point, although I've since found out that that the delimiters varies too, so I think I've got to bite the bullet and do some screen scraping for now at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the creator of the Stack Snippet that is used in [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/158100). I set out on creating that script to fully generate the content of that answer.

As [MichaelT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269332/is-there-an-easy-way-of-finding-out-what-mathjax-extensions-are-enabled-on-every?noredirect=1#comment872761_269332) also noticed and confirmed by [the answer from Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251229/158100) you found yourself, the information on additional extensions within MathJax is not exposed in the [2.2 version of the Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). My scripting effort stopped at the same point you're at now.

The *have a look at the page source* seems to be the most reliable way to get that info today. The answer I linked to is the best single source but is maintained by editing/updating the extra available extensions manually.